# Tracks of CSS grid not shrinking when other tracks grow

Tags: html, css, css-grid

In the following code, why do the grid track cells not dynamically shrink when the other cells are enlarged?

In the snippet, if you hover over any track section, that cell grows to 75% of the viewpoint, however rather than the other sections of the grid shrinking to accommodate the newly sized section, they all stay at their original size causing the cells to expand out beyond the size of the grid.

I would like to create sections of the grid that can be resized by hovering over them with the other sections of the grid shrinking to accommodate the new size.

Is there a way to do this, and more importantly, why does my code not work?

```css
.grid--container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 1fr) minmax(0, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: minmax(0, 1fr) minmax(0, 1fr);
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.track--section {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
}

.track--section:hover {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 75vh;
  width: 75vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid--container">
  <div class="track--section">section1</div>
  <div class="track--section">section2</div>
  <div class="track--section">section3</div>
  <div class="track--section">section4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the main issue is basically to understand the difference between `minmax(0,1fr)` and `1fr` and why the first one is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have `1fr` in **both** your row and column definitions, the horizontal and vertical space is *constrained* - so they will be *equally shared* by the grid items. Try changing this to *auto* for both rows and columns and you can see things working just about okay, but not perfect yet - note that there are *whitespaces* around the *hovered* grid items:

```css
.grid--container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto; /* changed */
  grid-template-rows: auto auto; /* changed */
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.track--section {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
}

.track--section:hover {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 75vh;
  width: 75vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid--container">
  <div class="track--section">section1</div>
  <div class="track--section">section2</div>
  <div class="track--section">section3</div>
  <div class="track--section">section4</div>
</div>
```

---

#### Solution

You can try this:

- a 2 column layout using `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr`
- *implicit rows* for this using `grid-auto-rows: 1fr`

See demo below:

```css
.grid--container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; /* 2 columns */
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr; /* implicit rows */
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.track--section {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
}

.track--section:hover {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 75vh;
  width: 75vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid--container">
  <div class="track--section">section1</div>
  <div class="track--section">section2</div>
  <div class="track--section">section3</div>
  <div class="track--section">section4</div>
</div>
```

You can read more about *Explicit and Implicit Grids* here: [CSS Grid unwanted column added automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55956781).

Comment: well that certainly seems like what I was looking for. I am still having a hard time wrapping my head around why it works. I am going to have to do some more reading on this. Thanks for your help!!!