# CSS Grid unwanted column added automatically

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Trying to group items in two separate line by CSS Grid using different class names. It works fine until in "red" group have no more elements then predefined rows (this case 3).

Can I somehow put the 4th "red" element in new row?

If there is only 3 "red" element, everything works fine.

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  grid-row-start: 5;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="blue">
    <h2>1</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="red">
    <h2>2</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="blue">
    <h2>3</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="blue">
    <h2>4</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="red">
    <h2>5</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="red">
    <h2>6</h2>
  </li>
  <!-- If you delete this (or any other "red") "li" element then it's working fine -->
  <li class="red">
    <h2>7</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="blue">
    <h2>8</h2>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't see how, the 4th column is there because it's part of the implicit grid. Once created it can't be ignored.

Comment: Thank you! 

I searched now what is implicit grid. My problem is because of it. But how can I put  my content from implicit grid to explicit? The "nth-child()" method is'nt good because "red" and "blue" elements order may vary.

Can you suggest a different approach to this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are specifying all the `red` elements into the fifth row by using `grid-row-start: 5`. Yes, the red elements are *placed* to the fifth row, and that is not immediately visible as you haven't specified an *explicit row definition* (say using `grid-template-rows`).

---

#### Implicit Rows

You can define the *implicit row* definition using something like `grid-auto-rows: 50px` and see that the `red` element are actually in the fifth row:

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 50px; /* specify row height */
  list-style: none; /* remove bullets */
  padding: 0; /* remove default ul padding */
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  grid-row-start: 5;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid #bbb; /* border for illustration */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="blue">
    <h2>1</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="red">
    <h2>2</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="blue">
    <h2>3</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="blue">
    <h2>4</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="red">
    <h2>5</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="red">
    <h2>6</h2>
  </li>
  <!-- If you delete this (or any other "red") "li" element then it's working fine -->
  <li class="red">
    <h2>7</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="blue">
    <h2>8</h2>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

#### Implicit Columns

Now your question is why the *fourth* red item is in the same row - because you have *placed* all of them in the same fifth row. An *implicit grid column* is created with auto width - you can control this width using `grid-auto-columns`:

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 50px; /* specify row height */
  grid-auto-columns: 100px; /* specify column width */
  list-style: none; /* remove bullets */
  padding: 0; /* remove default ul padding */
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  grid-row-start: 5;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid #bbb; /* border for illustration */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="blue">
    <h2>1</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="red">
    <h2>2</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="blue">
    <h2>3</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="blue">
    <h2>4</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="red">
    <h2>5</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="red">
    <h2>6</h2>
  </li>
  <!-- If you delete this (or any other "red") "li" element then it's working fine -->
  <li class="red">
    <h2>7</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="blue">
    <h2>8</h2>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

#### Solution

You can do this to *group* them:

- set `order: 1` to the *red* items so that they always come after the *blue* ones,
- set the first `red` element to the first column using `grid-column: 1` and the rest will be auto-placed using `grid-column: auto`.

See demo below:

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  list-style: none; /* remove bullets */
  padding: 0; /* remove default ul padding */
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  order: 1; /* red items have higher order */
}

.red { /* first red element into first column */
  grid-column: 1;
}

.red ~ .red { /* subsequent red elements auto-placed */
  grid-column: auto;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid #bbb; /* border for illustration */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="blue">
    <h2>1</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="red">
    <h2>2</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="blue">
    <h2>3</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="blue">
    <h2>4</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="red">
    <h2>5</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="red">
    <h2>6</h2>
  </li>
  <!-- If you delete this (or any other "red") "li" element then it's working fine -->
  <li class="red">
    <h2>7</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="blue">
    <h2>8</h2>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

## **Explicit vs Implicit Grid**

---

#### Explicit grid

*Explicit grid* is the grid that you define using `grid-template-columns`, `grid-template-rows`, `grid-template-areas` and related *shorthand properties* - see excerpts below from W3C:

> [**`Explicit Grid (W3C)`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#explicit-grids)
>
> The three properties grid-template-rows, grid-template-columns, and
>   grid-template-areas together define the explicit grid of a grid
>   container. The final grid may end up larger due to grid items placed
>   outside the explicit grid; in this case implicit tracks will be
>   created, these implicit tracks will be sized by the grid-auto-rows and
>   grid-auto-columns properties.

---

See an example below of and *explicit* 2x2 grid which we will come back to shortly:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 50px;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}
/* styles */
.wrapper > div { border: 1px solid cadetblue; background: lightblue; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div>
</div>
```

---

#### Implicit grid

If you have more content or elements *inside* the grid container but *outside* the *explicit grid definition*, then *that* is part of what is called as the *implicit grid*.

You control the size of your *implicit grid* using `grid-auto-rows` and `grid-auto-columns` properties.

> [**`Implicit Grid (W3C)`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#implicit-grids)
>
> The `grid-template-rows`, `grid-template-columns`, and `grid-template-areas`
>   properties define a fixed number of tracks that form the explicit
>   grid. When grid items are positioned outside of these bounds, the grid
>   container generates implicit grid tracks by adding implicit grid lines
>   to the grid. These lines together with the explicit grid form the
>   implicit grid. The `grid-auto-rows` and `grid-auto-columns` properties
>   size these implicit grid tracks.

---

You can see *implicit rows* created if you have more *grid items* in the example above - these rows can be sized using `grid-auto-rows` property:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 50px;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-auto-rows: 25px; /* size of implicit rows */
}
/* styles */
.wrapper > div { border: 1px solid cadetblue; background: lightblue; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div>
  <div>5</div><div>6</div><div>7</div><div>8</div>
</div>
```

---

To have a look at *implicit columns* created you can try placing some *grid items* beyond the second column - these rows can be sized using `grid-auto-columns` property. See how a new column is created and how the grid behaves:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 50px;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-auto-rows: 25px; /* size of implicit rows */
  grid-auto-columns: 25px; /* size of implicit columns */
}

div:nth-child(5), div:nth-child(6) {
  grid-column: 3; /* place in thrid column */
}

/* styles */
.wrapper > div { border: 1px solid cadetblue; background: lightblue; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div>
  <div>5</div><div>6</div><div>7</div><div>8</div>
</div>
```