# Why grid-template-rows track pattern does not repeat like grid-template-columns

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Here is a simple grid (there are a total of twenty `.grid_item`s):

```
  <div class="grid">
    <h1 class="grid_item">300 px row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">300 px row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">300 px row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">100 px row, 1fr column </h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">100 px row, 1fr column </h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">100 px row , 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr; /*Entire column is 1fr 1fr 1fr*/
  grid-template-rows: 600px 1fr 100px; /*Only first three rowsare 600px 1fr 100px; ?*/
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
```

Note: what I am going to try and explain can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/xth3ky0m/3/

When the grid is displayed, every `<h1 class = "grid_item"><h1>` is displayed according to `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;` but only the first three rows follow `grid-template-rows: 300px 1fr 100px;`. After the first three rows, each row is just `1fr`.  The `300px 1fr 100px` row pattern does not automatically repeat like the `1fr 1fr 1fr` column pattern. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CSS grid layout by default fills all the *explicit* rows (note that *explicit* rows or columns are that which you specify using properties like `grid-template-columns`, `grid-template-rows`, `grid-template-areas`) and creates *new rows as necessary* (*implicit* rows). This behavior is due to `grid-auto-flow` property - see the below excerpt from MDN:

> [`grid-auto-flow: row`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow#Values)
>
> Is a keyword specifying that the auto-placement algorithm places
>   items, by filling each row in turn, adding new rows as necessary. If
>   neither row nor column is provided, row is assumed.

---

#### Auto-flow in row direction

This explains why the *grid items* fills all the *explicit* columns in a row and then moves on to the next row creating an *implicit* row if needed. You can specify the size of *implicit rows* (from the 4<sup>th</sup> row in your example) using `grid-auto-rows` property:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 300px 1fr 100px;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-auto-rows: 50px; /* size implicit rows */
}

.grid_item {
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 95, 197);
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 95, 107, 0.8);
  padding: 0.2em;
  margin: 0; /* reset h1 margin to see grid better */
  overflow: hidden; /* hide overflow text */
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="grid">
    <h1 class="grid_item">300 px row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">300 px row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">300 px row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">100 px row, 1fr column </h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">100 px row, 1fr column </h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">100 px row , 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

#### Auto-flow in column direction

The *grid items* here fills all the *explicit* rows in a column and then moves on to the next column creating an *implicit* column if needed. You can specify the size of *implicit columns* (from the 4<sup>th</sup> row in your example) using `grid-auto-columns` property:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 300px 1fr 100px;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-auto-flow: column; /* flow in column direction */
  grid-auto-columns: 50px; /* size implicit columns */
}

.grid_item {
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 95, 197);
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 95, 107, 0.8);
  padding: 0.2em;
  margin: 0; /* reset h1 margin to see grid better */
  overflow: hidden; /* hide overflow text */
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="grid">
    <h1 class="grid_item">300 px row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">300 px row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">300 px row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">100 px row, 1fr column </h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">100 px row, 1fr column </h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">100 px row , 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
    <h1 class="grid_item">1fr row, 1fr column</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

So coming to your questions:

> After the first three rows, each row is just 1fr.

It is *auto* and not 1fr - you can control this using `grid-auto-rows` property.

> The `300px 1fr 100px` row pattern does not automatically repeat like the `1fr 1fr 1fr` column pattern.

*Implicit* rows are created by filling available *explicit* columns by default. If you switch to `grid-auto-flow: column` you can have it the other way around.

---

You can read more about *Explicit and Implicit Grids* here: [CSS Grid unwanted column added automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55956781)