# struggling with css grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I would like to align horizontally on a single line a bunch of divs of class `a` within a `container` div.

Why is the below css code not working ?

```
.a {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#container {
  display:grid;
  grid-auto-columns: minmax(10px, 35px);
  grid-template-rows:1fr;
}
```

I have created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8vg6pz3n/1/) for it. I was expecting the divs 1 to 6 there to all be on the same line but I get the following result :

[image: the non-desired result]

Comment: use `grid-auto-flow: column`, see https://jsfiddle.net/ab401dmn/ an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56062699

Comment: `display: flex;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the default flow <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow)</sup> to column:

```css
.a {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: minmax(10px, 35px);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow:column; /* added */
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="a">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="a">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="a">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="a">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="a">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="a">
    6
  </div>
</div>
```

Or define a template column like below:

```css
.a {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fill, minmax(10px, 35px));
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="a">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="a">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="a">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="a">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="a">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="a">
    6
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

CSS:

```
#container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(75px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 1rem;
}
```

Note: Its align horizontally on a single line.